# how to read data from a file in this exercise?

Tags: c, stdio

I have to do this exercise:

short explanation:

> read a file, and store informations in a struct pointed to by a pointer.

long explanation:

> I have a struct "person", and it contains: char name[256]; unsigned int age.

```
struct person {
    char name[256];
    unsigned int age;
};
```

> I have to implement this function:

```
void person_read (FILE *f, struct person *pp);
```

> I have to read informations with this formatting style:

```
<person's name> <whitespace> <age> 
<person's name> <whitespace> <age> 
<person's name> <whitespace> <age> 
<person's name> <whitespace> <age>
```

and store each data in the struct pointed to by this pointer.

the problem is that I have no idea how to read person's name, skip whitespace and then read age. How can I set up a reading function like this: 1) read person's name, 2) skip whitespace, 3) read age ?

fgetc() function is not a solution, because it reads only 1 character, and a person's name doesn't have 1 single character. on the other hand, fscanf() function reads everything.

my idea is to use 1) read, 2) check, 3) use

1. read a char, check if it's not a whitespace, if it's true, then store in the array name of the struct. (if it's true, that means that in the array I have full person's name).
2. read again, and again, and so on until a whitespace it's reached. Then skip the whitespace.
3. read age, and store it in the struct (unsigned int age).

but I think I'm overcomplicating the job. is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution is:

```
int r = fscanf(f, "%255s %u\n", p->name, &p->age);
```

where `p` your person pointer.  You want to check that `r` is `2` in this case so you have a valid data for both fields.

Comment: but I have whitespaces, does it skip them?

Comment: Try. and let me know.